# Why do emails I send to a group that I am a member of not appear in my personal inbox?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

This is a question about the email sending behaviour for Groups in Outlook. I am accessing my mailbox using Outlook Web Access (OWA).

When I send an email to a group that I am a member of, and I have set the option to 'Follow in inbox', I expect to see the email I sent appear in my own personal Inbox - but it doesn't. What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-groups/feature-update-email-sending-behavior-for-groups-in-outlook/m-p/48673):

> Feature update: Email sending behavior for Groups in Outlook
>
> We have recently fixed the email sending behavior to a group, where senders had complained about receiving the emails they send to a group, back in their personal inbox. With this fix, senders will no longer receive the emails they send to a group, back in their personal inbox. The sender can receive email sent to group in their Inbox, they have to login to their mailbox using OWA, and then Settings->Mail->Groups->"Send me a copy of email I send to a group"
>
> The primary complaints we heard were about reading the same message users sent to a group multiple times - in their sent messages, and their inbox.
>
> We believe sending an email to a person or to a group should be consistent, and this circling back of an email from a group was just leading to confusion, unnecessary triage, and inconvenience for a lot of our users.